# Ajax4jsf File Upload

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload

I want to upload a file with AJAX in a JSF application. The idea is that as soon as the user selects the file, it is uploaded, and a preview is shown. Currently I am using t:inputFileUpload and have the code to insert the image in a database and show the preview. I tried a4j:support but it did not work.

Many thanks,
Panayiotis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Richfaces file-upload component

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf

Regards.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up using.